# How to make vertical annotation when using Google Charts DataTable roles?

Tags: javascript, gwt, google-visualization

I am using the Google Chart Tools DataTable Roles feature to annotate LineChart as mentioned in the below link:-
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles

But the annotations are coming Horizontal and not vertical. For example "Started Using Spreadsheets" annotation below is vertical which is what I want but for me its not coming vertical.
[image]

I am using the below code to add annotated column:-

```
addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

You are close!
Since you have regular annotations ready, just add to your chart options:
`annotations: {style: 'line'}`.

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/tVCv9/268/

Read the docs on annotations: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles?hl=fr#annotationrole

Good luck!

Comment: JsFiddle link is no longer valid.

Comment: The annotation column must be set before other columns too. When I tried defining the annotation column as the last column, the annotation does not appear as full vertical line, but only appeared like label on top of the bar.