# Using "role:'annotation'" to place text vertically

Tags: google-visualization

I have used the `rotate:90`, styles and other attemps.

```
data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});
```

Please see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qQPr.png):

There is the "`annotations:{style:'line'}`" option but it does create a unsightly middle centered line.. That's not what I want.. I just want to rotate the text 90º.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make vertical annotation when using Google Charts DataTable roles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913637/how-to-make-vertical-annotation-when-using-google-charts-datatable-roles)